# Show different layout for both orientations

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android application i designed two different layouts with same file name say my_profile.xml, and stored in two different directories i.e, 1) res/layout, 2) res/layout-land. Now the problem is if i start activity in Portrait mode it loads Portrait mode layout but after changing orientation it doesn't change layout, But if i start activity in Landscape mode it loads layout of landscape i.e, perfect. Problem is only when i change orientation, it doesn't handle it automatically. Can any one tell me, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following :

1) In manifest file  check for the below line in your activity

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

2) Override the below function

```
@Override

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Log.d(tag,"onconfig");

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                   // do something
            Log.d(tag,"land");
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
              // do something
        }
    }
```

-Preeya

Comment: Well preeya i fixed it. The problem was "screenSize" Previously i used android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" but after removing "screenSize" my problem is resolved. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.xml make the changes like this,,,,,

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

dont use configuartionChanges="orientation"

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file. If you have the following in your activity then REMOVE IT:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
```

`orientation` causes the the activity to resort to the same layout rather than creating a new one.